How to develop Relative Percent Difference Function for dataframe?
I am new to R and so I assume this is something rather simple but I can not find an adequate explanation online or a easy way to go about it. I have a table consisting of rows containing quality control values and original values. I want to create a function that goes through each of the rows, obtains the relative percent difference (RPD) between the Value_QC and Value_Results and then creates a new row on the end with the result. I believe what I need is a function that iterates the RPD formula (attached below) through each row in the column, pulling the Value_QC and Value_Results as the variables. There are also some NAs in the value columns, and I would like to set those to 0 if possible but not sure how to do that either. I know what I want to accomplish, I just don't have the skills yet in function building in order to develop it. Any help, especially with explanation, would help immensely! Thanks!

dput(head(QCandResults))
structure(list(anl_short = c("Water Temp               ", "Water Temp               ", 
"Water Temp               ", "Water Temp               ", "Water Temp               ", 
"Water Temp               "), Sample_Num = c(202309111300030, 
2.02308301e+14, 202308091000030, 202308221000020, 202308031100110, 
202308301000060), QC_SAMPLE = c(202309111341030, 202308301041000, 
202308091041030, 202308221041020, 202308031141110, 202308301041060
), Loc_ID = c("GRR20001", "CFK20001", "CCK20001", "CRR20001", 
"BVR20001", "CFK20001"), Units_QC = c("deg C", "deg C", "deg C", 
"deg C", "deg C", "deg C"), Value_QC = c(19.26, 27.01, 17.19, 
26.39, 8.51, 11.6), Text_Value_QC = c("19.26", "27.01", "17.19", 
"26.39", "8.51", "11.6"), QC_Type = c("DUP", "DUP", "DUP", "DUP", 
"DUP", "DUP"), Units_Results = c("deg C", "deg C", "deg C", "deg C", 
"deg C", "deg C"), Value_Results = c(19.39, 26.95, 17.28, 26.3, 
8.53, 11.53), Text_Value_Results = c("19.39", "26.95", "17.28", 
"26.3", "8.53", "11.53")), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 
11L), class = "data.frame")

  anl_short   Sample_Num    QC_SAMPLE   Loc_ID Units_QC Value_QC Text_Value_QC QC_Type Units_Results Value_Results Text_Value_Results
1  Water Temp                2.023091e+14 2.023091e+14 GRR20001    deg C    19.26         19.26     DUP         deg C         19.39              19.39
3  Water Temp                2.023083e+14 2.023083e+14 CFK20001    deg C    27.01         27.01     DUP         deg C         26.95              26.95
5  Water Temp                2.023081e+14 2.023081e+14 CCK20001    deg C    17.19         17.19     DUP         deg C         17.28              17.28
7  Water Temp                2.023082e+14 2.023082e+14 CRR20001    deg C    26.39         26.39     DUP         deg C         26.30               26.3
9  Water Temp                2.023080e+14 2.023080e+14 BVR20001    deg C     8.51          8.51     DUP         deg C          8.53               8.53
11 Water Temp                2.023083e+14 2.023083e+14 CFK20001    deg C    11.60          11.6     DUP         deg C         11.53              11.53


Please provide a rerefenre to the formula. It looks like that the absolute value ("$|x|$") is used  which is confusing.

Will do. Absolute value is used in this case. Here is my reference: https://dec.vermont.gov/sites/dec/files/How%20To%20Calculate%20RPD.xlsx

This can be easily done in base R without loops.
Define a function
RPD = \(x1, x2) { 
  ## the following line is not needed   
  x1[is.na(x1)] = 0L; x2[is.na(x2)] = 0L 
  ## but there since you mention it 
  (x1 - x2) / ((x1 + x2) * .5) * 100L
  }
## i.e. given your toy data 
# RPD = \(x1, x2) (x1 - x2) / ((x1 + x2) * .5) * 100L
## would be enough

where \(x1, x2) is shorthand notation for function(x1, x2),
and apply it:
1) with within() like
> within(QCandResults, {RPD = RPD(Value_QC, Value_Results)})
                   anl_short   Sample_Num    QC_SAMPLE   Loc_ID Units_QC Value_QC Text_Value_QC QC_Type Units_Results Value_Results Text_Value_Results       RPD
1  Water Temp                2.023091e+14 2.023091e+14 GRR20001    deg C    19.26         19.26     DUP         deg C         19.39              19.39 -0.6727038
3  Water Temp                2.023083e+14 2.023083e+14 CFK20001    deg C    27.01         27.01     DUP         deg C         26.95              26.95  0.2223870
5  Water Temp                2.023081e+14 2.023081e+14 CCK20001    deg C    17.19         17.19     DUP         deg C         17.28              17.28 -0.5221932
7  Water Temp                2.023082e+14 2.023082e+14 CRR20001    deg C    26.39         26.39     DUP         deg C         26.30               26.3  0.3416208
9  Water Temp                2.023080e+14 2.023080e+14 BVR20001    deg C     8.51          8.51     DUP         deg C          8.53               8.53 -0.2347418
11 Water Temp                2.023083e+14 2.023083e+14 CFK20001    deg C    11.60          11.6     DUP         deg C         11.53              11.53  0.6052745

or 2) with transform()
transform(QCandResults, RPD = RPD(Value_QC, Value_Results))

or 3) with with()
QCandResults$RPD = with(QCandResults, RPD(Value_QC, Value_Results))

This is less to write than the very basic 4)
QCandResults$RPD = RPD(QCandResults$Value_QC, QCandResults$Value_Results)

Just use one (once).

This worked perfectly! Thank you. One question. What is the purpose behind the "L" after the 0's and 100 in the function?

To ensure we are dealing with an integer. To specify it use the L suffix. Imo, it is good practice to integrate it in the work flow without exception. Wrap (x1 - x2), i.e. the numerator, in abs() to follow the definition.

You can do this with the mutate() function from the dplyr package. Here is an example:
df <- mutate(df, 
   Value_Results = if_else(is.na(Value_Results), 0, Value_Results), # Replaces NA with 0 in Value_results
   Value_QC = if_else(is.na(Value_QC), 0, Value_QC),# Replaces NA with 0 in Value_QC
   RPD = ((Value_Results-Value_QC)/((Value_Results+Value_QC)/2))*100) # Calculates RPD

The mutate function modifies (or creates) a column in the dataset, first we replace all NA in our two columns by using is.na() which will return TRUE if a value is NA. Then we use that output in the dplyr if_else function which will return 0 if the is.na returns TRUE or just return the current value if the is.na returns FALSE, finally we create a new column RPD by implementing the formula you included above and assigning it to RPD.

calling your data.frame structure some_temps, first add a 'receiver' column called rpd_qc_rslts
some_temps['rpd_qc_rslts'] <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(some_temps)) {

some_temps$rpd_qc_rslts[i] <- ((some_temps$Value_QC[i] - some_temps$Value_Results[i])/((some_temps$Value_QC[i] + some_temps$Value_Results[i])/2)) * 100

}

some_temps$rpd_qc_rslts

[1] -0.6727038  0.2223870 -0.5221932  0.3416208 -0.2347418  0.6052745


Thanks man! I really appreciate your help. I'll try this out tomorrow and see if I get what's needed.

when I started I used loops when I could figure them out. What is consistent between the the dplyr::mutate approach and a for is establishing where the new value is going, pre-allocation. As the issue is about x (Value_QC) with regards to (wrt) y (Value_Results), abs() wouldn't  be appropriate here as it's introduction would lose the wrt information, whereas swapping x for y would merely change signs.
